# BIRT chart label missing

Tags: java, data-visualization, birt

I am drawing a bar chart using [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/).

- On the staging server, all the labels on the x-axis are showing, irrespective of the number of bars.
- On the production server, alternate labels will be missing if the number of bars are above 30.

**I want the labels to show all the time.**

I have checked the report design on both staging and production and they are the same bar some text and URLs. `<staggered>` is set to `false` and `interval` is set to `1`.

Having received this task yesterday and knowing next to nothing about Java or BIRT, where else should I look to debug this?

The environments are running different versions of BIRT runtime, but when I swapped out the staging's runtime version with the production's version, there was an error so I had to revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Just double click on the Chart, a window opens, where you can edit the chart.
In that window move to **Format chart** tab. In **Format chart** tab, you have list of menu's in left side bar. In that you can configure to display your labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting stagger as true.

It worked for me.

This will adjust width of labels.